# What font is this exactly Asana Math?

Tags: fonts, asana

I am trying to do some edits in Adobe Illustrator off of some fonts generated in the code below.  In Acrobat, the font shows up as Asana Math.  In the OTF file downloaded from CTAN, I do not see any Italics variation.  Now I am not sure what this font really is.  Can you help me identify the font:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}


\usepackage{unicode-math}  % loads 'fontspec' automatically

\setmainfont{Fira Sans Light}[
     Numbers       = OldStyle,
     BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
     ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
     BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
\setsansfont{Fira Sans Light}[
     Numbers       = OldStyle,
     BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
     ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
     BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
% For source code
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[
     BoldFont=Source Code Pro]

%% Math font
\setmathfont{Asana Math} % or some other suitable font

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
-2f_{c}\quad 2W \quad 2f_{c} \quad 2W \quad f \quad V(f)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have the pdf so you can get the font list from acrobat or the pdffonts utility, that's far more accurate than asking people to debug a png image of the output by eye, or trusting that their font setup will use the same font versions that you used. what fonts does pdffonts list for the pdf from the above example?

Comment: It says Anana Math for the italicized "f".  Under the Asana Math, I do not find any italics variation.

Comment: it's a math font, so you'd expect sloped letters  wouldn't you? in the math italic slot U+1D453 I would assume.

Comment: Can this font be reproduced in Windows to be used else where like in Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: well you can get the basic glyphs as its a normal OTF font, presumably illustrator doesn't know how to interpret the OTF table so math specific rendering like stretchy brackets won't be there.

Comment: Besides the glyphs, can the italic math font be reproduced?

Comment: it's not a separate font just different unicode slots, try this text for example  

Comment: How do I go about getting that font in your example?

Comment: I did not select a font: I just entered the unicode characters and your browser shows them in whatever font you have set up locally to read that Unicode range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85121/discussion-between-joe-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 6):

The font will be Asana Math as reported.

You do not see separate "italic variant" as OpenType Math fonts do not use separate fonts for italic, fraktur, etc math alphabets but rather (mostly) use the unicode range starting at U+1D400 which contains these math alphabets.

So for example, without changing font,    is bold math italic ℍ   is math double-struck, with the H being U+1D46F and U+210D respectively.

Comment: Hello, I am still not sure of what to make of your suggestion.  In summary, I will not be able to generate the Asana Math italic font to be used in Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: @Joe no, exactly the opposite, just select the font and add the characters, eg try cutting and pasting my bold italic  